# Duplicated site name after publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Currently I am refactoring the site written on ASP.NET MVC5. 
It already has published-version on some remote server (Windows Server 2012, IIS). Every time after some code refactored I do publish again and replace some folders\files on remote server.

What I found and want to know if it is a bug or something else :
In Debug mode I can access site only as localhost:**** and it is correct. 
After publish everybody can access site by two url : '**sitename.com**' (OK) or '**sitename.sitename.com**' (Hmm?). 'sitename.sitename.sitename.com' doesn't work - OK. I think this happened because of some settings of IIS\Server isn't it?

It is not the urgent problem, but I want to know why it happened. Currently I can't contact to previous developers, what is the sad moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that "sitename.sitename.com" is a subdomaian of sitename.com go to Your hosting provider control panel and deactivate sitename.sitename.com subdomain.

Comment: Is there any security risks if I leave it as it is? Or will it influence to SEO?

Comment: there's no securicty risk, simply deactivate it(don't delete it if You don't want to) , if they where some problems activate it again .,About seo..sitename/blog.com is SEO friendly but blog.sitename.com isn't Seo friendly, so Your's subdomain  isnt friendly from Seo point of view.